# JS Need to add value every 1.5 sec

Tags: javascript, html

This is my code that is unfortunately not working.

It is taking value from html (600) and then dividing it (var f = 600/20). It should start onclick button (which already has onclick function).

```js
function enemy() {
  var iFrequency = 2500;
  var myInterval = 0;
  var e = document.getElementById('stre').innerHTML;
  var f = e / 20;

  function startLoop() {
    if (myInterval > 0) clearInterval(myInterval); // stop
    myInterval = setInterval("doSomething()", iFrequency);
  }

  function doSomething() {
    var label = document.getElementById('wallvalue');
    label.innerHTML = parseInt(label.innerHTML) + f;
    document.getElementById('wallvalue').style.color = 'red';
    document.getElementById('resultr').innerHTML = f;
    document.getElementById('resultr').style.color = 'red';
    document.getElementById('resultrc').innerHTML = f;
    document.getElementById('resultrc').style.color = 'red';
  }
```

```html
<BUTTON class="doit" onclick="damagec(); iFrequency+=1000; startLoop(); return false;"><b>FIGHT</b></BUTTON>
```

Comment: I made you a snippet. Now add the missing HTML AND script to it - also `setInterval(doSomething, iFrequency);`

Comment: `startLoop` is not defined in global scope so the inline event handler cannot call that function. That's at least one thing that doesn't work. Please provide a [mcve].

Comment: ` damagec is not defined`

Answer (score 0):

Looks like youve tried to do some inheritance, but your code is not working in any way. You may do this:

```js
function enemy(name) { // a constructor for our enemy
  this.name=name;
  this.iFrequency = 2500;
  this.myInterval = false;
  this.el=document.createElement("div");
  document.body.appendChild(this.el);
  this.f = 1;
}

enemy.prototype={ //functions for all enemys
  startLoop:function() {
    if (this.myInterval) clearInterval(this.myInterval); // stop
    this.myInterval = setInterval(this.doSomething.bind(this), this.iFrequency);
  },
  doSomething:function () {
    this.el.innerHTML = this.name+":"+(++this.f);
    this.el.style.color = 'red';
  }
};

var Monster=new enemy("Monster");//create a new Enemey
var button=document.createElement("button");
button.textContent="Start Monster";
document.body.appendChild(button);

button.onclick=Monster.startLoop.bind(Monster);
```

Answer (score 0):

I managed to get it done. Thank you all for the answers!

```
function enemy(){
    var e=600;
    var f=600/20;
    document.getElementById('resultr').innerHTML = f;
    document.getElementById('resultr').style.color = 'red';
    document.getElementById('resultrc').innerHTML = f;
    document.getElementById('resultrc').style.color = 'red';

    var intervalID = window.setInterval(myCallback, 3000);

    function myCallback() {
    var label = document.getElementById('wallvalue');
    label.innerHTML = parseInt(label.innerHTML) + f;
    document.getElementById('wallvalue').style.color = 'red';
    }
}
```